# array_map with an array of variable names

Tags: php

How can I use array_map to transform an array of variable names into an array of the values of those names? For example:

```php
$arg_array = array('foo', 'bar');
$foo = "asdf";
$bar = "qwer";

print_r(array_map(function($a) {return ${$a};}, $arg_array)); //doesn't work

var_dump(${$arg_array[0]}); //works
```

Seems like it should be straightforward, but the `array_map` function returns `Undefined variable: foo` and `Undefined variable: bar`, then shows an array of `''`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a scoping issue.

Adding a `global ${$a}` will help:

```
print_r(array_map(function($a) {global ${$a};return ${$a};}, $arg_array)); //doesn't
```

At least if the outer block is the global namespace...

Otherwise this kind of creating names of variables dynamically is not a good sign... This cases are generally convertible to arrays, and the life is much easier with arrays.

Comment: Friggin' scope. Yeah, that was it.